# How to create inverse png image?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, onpaint

i am creating png image which painted on my base, from the base i can save a png image, for your reference

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
 ....
g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x, y), new Point(x1, y1));
 .....
base.OnPaint(e);

using (var bmp = new Bitmap(500, 50))
{
    base.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 50));
    bmp.Save(outPath);
}
```

this is single color transparency image, now how do i can inverse this image like png filled with any color and the real image portion should be transparent, is there any possibilities?

bit detail : so transparent will go nontransparent and where there is fill will go to transparent

Comment: I used vectors to make blazing fast code
[Check my post for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44467764/6176081)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT** *(thanks for [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259137/thomas) notation)*

```
public void ApplyInvert()  
{  
    byte A, R, G, B;  
    Color pixelColor;  

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmapImage.Height; y++)  
    {  
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmapImage.Width; x++)  
        {  
            pixelColor = bitmapImage.GetPixel(x, y);  
            A = (byte)(255 - pixelColor.A); 
            R = pixelColor.R;  
            G = pixelColor.G;  
            B = pixelColor.B;  
            bitmapImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb((int)A, (int)R, (int)G, (int)B));  
        }  
    }  
}
```

from here : [Image Processing in C#: Inverting an image](http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/image-processing-in-c-sharp-inverting-an-image/)

Comment: nooo, i think this is for inverting a color (negative), my question is inverting image of transparent. so transparent will go nontransparent and where there is fill will go to transparent

Comment: @manny Use the code above, but only invert the A component (`A = 255 - pixelColor.A;`) and leave R, G and B alone. (And remove all the casts, they aren't needed if you define A, R, G and B as ints.)

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it is perfect, i am getting my result. Thank you Thomas

Answer (score 8):

There's a faster way if you're willing to use [`unsafe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx) code:

```
private unsafe void Invert(Bitmap bmp)
{
    int w = bmp.Width, h = bmp.Height;
    BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    int* bytes = (int*)data.Scan0;
    for ( int i = w*h-1; i >= 0; i-- )
        bytes[i] = ~bytes[i];
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

Note that this doesn't care about the colors and will invert those as well. If you wish to use a specific color, then the code will have to be modified a bit.

Comment: Aded a link. Basically it's a code that uses pointers (like that `int*` there). The .NET runtime cannot verify that this code won't do something stupid, like writing a memory that isn't allocated, hence the name "unsafe". Because it can corrupt the program memory if you're not careful. To compile this code you will have to enable unsafe code in the project options (it's off by default), and I think there were some security implications too (unsafe code doesn't work in partially trusted assemblies or something).

Comment: `unsafe` code isn't necessarily bad. It can give great performance boosts, like in this case. You just need to be careful with it and be aware of the security implications.

Comment: Not correctly inverting.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who wants a fast method for inverting Bitmap colors without using unsafe:

```
public static void BitmapInvertColors(Bitmap bitmapImage)
{
    var bitmapRead   = bitmapImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapImage.Width, bitmapImage.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    var bitmapLength = bitmapRead.Stride * bitmapRead.Height;
    var bitmapBGRA   = new byte[bitmapLength];
    Marshal.Copy(bitmapRead.Scan0, bitmapBGRA, 0, bitmapLength);
    bitmapImage.UnlockBits(bitmapRead);

    for (int i = 0; i < bitmapLength; i += 4)
    {
        bitmapBGRA[i]     = (byte)(255 - bitmapBGRA[i]);
        bitmapBGRA[i + 1] = (byte)(255 - bitmapBGRA[i + 1]);
        bitmapBGRA[i + 2] = (byte)(255 - bitmapBGRA[i + 2]);
        //        [i + 3] = ALPHA.
    }

    var bitmapWrite = bitmapImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapImage.Width, bitmapImage.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    Marshal.Copy(bitmapBGRA, 0, bitmapWrite.Scan0, bitmapLength);
    bitmapImage.UnlockBits(bitmapWrite);
}
```

Bitmap GetPixel and SetPixel are extremly slow, this method works by copying the Bitmap pixels into a byte array, which you can then loop through and change, before finally copying the pixels back.

Answer (score 0):

When you say invert the transparent sections into color, are you storing the real colors in the PNG image just set to full transparency? A lot of programs will optimize a png by removing the color data from transparency so you can't reverse it.

Colors can be converted to transparency
But transparency (without underlying colors) cannot be converted to color.

If your lucky your PNG will be non optimized and still have the original color data intact, but if your doing this from user input then it won't work for a high percentage of cases.

Comment: Yeah, mine is single color image, either it will be black or white, so inverse will have the same color, i was worrying about alpha