# Inverting image returns a black image

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, gdi+

I want to invert an Image object. Currently my code looks like this:

```
    private Image Invert(Image img)
    {
        var bmpPicture = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
        var iaPicture = new ImageAttributes();
        var cmPicture = new ColorMatrix { Matrix00 = -1, Matrix11 = -1, Matrix22 = -1 };
        iaPicture.SetColorMatrix(cmPicture);
        var gfxPicture = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        var rctPicture = new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
        gfxPicture.DrawImage(img, rctPicture, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, iaPicture);
        return bmpPicture;
    }
```

However, when I run this, and show it in a `PictureBox`, the result is a black image. I'm running this in Visual Studio 2012 under Windows 8 Release preview. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You need to set Matrix33 = 1 and Matrix44 = 1 as well in order to preserve the identity for those items

Comment: IF the image is 8bpp, you can just invert its pallete.

Answer (score 11):

Try this: http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2009/11/13/using-colormatrix-for-creating-negative-image/

```
public Bitmap Transform(Bitmap source)
{
    //create a blank bitmap the same size as original
    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);

    //get a graphics object from the new image
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);

    // create the negative color matrix
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
    {
        new float[] {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, -1, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        new float[] {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
    }); 

    // create some image attributes
    ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();

    attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);

    g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
                0, 0, source.Width, source.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

    //dispose the Graphics object
    g.Dispose();

    return newBitmap;
}
```

Comment: I copy-pasted it. It created the same black image!

Comment: Did you scroll down to the ACTUAL solution, or just copy the first thing that looked like code?

Comment: What about invert a Graphics colors? Like, invert the image on the OnPaint event.

Answer (score 4):

Fast alternative to using a ColorMatrix for pixel manipulation:

```
public static void BitmapInvertColors(Bitmap bitmapImage)
{
    var bitmapRead   = bitmapImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapImage.Width, bitmapImage.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    var bitmapLength = bitmapRead.Stride * bitmapRead.Height;
    var bitmapBGRA   = new byte[bitmapLength];
    Marshal.Copy(bitmapRead.Scan0, bitmapBGRA, 0, bitmapLength);
    bitmapImage.UnlockBits(bitmapRead);

    for (int i = 0; i < bitmapLength; i += 4)
    {
        bitmapBGRA[i]     = (byte)(255 - bitmapBGRA[i]);
        bitmapBGRA[i + 1] = (byte)(255 - bitmapBGRA[i + 1]);
        bitmapBGRA[i + 2] = (byte)(255 - bitmapBGRA[i + 2]);
        //        [i + 3] = ALPHA.
    }

    var bitmapWrite = bitmapImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapImage.Width, bitmapImage.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    Marshal.Copy(bitmapBGRA, 0, bitmapWrite.Scan0, bitmapLength);
    bitmapImage.UnlockBits(bitmapWrite);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

VB version of Dan's Answer. It works like a charm !!

```
 Public Function Transform(source As Bitmap) As Bitmap
    'create a blank bitmap the same size as original
    Dim newBitmap As New Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height)

    'get a graphics object from the new image
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap)

    ' create the negative color matrix
    Dim colorMatrix As New ColorMatrix(New Single()() {New Single() {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, New Single() {0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, New Single() {0, 0, -1, 0, 0}, New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, New Single() {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}})

    ' create some image attributes
    Dim attributes As New ImageAttributes()

    attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix)

    g.DrawImage(source, New Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), 0, 0, source.Width, source.Height, _
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes)

    'dispose the Graphics object
    g.Dispose()

    Return newBitmap
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

By inverting, do you mean creating a negative? If yes here is a snippet:

```
public void ApplyInvert()
{
    byte A, R, G, B;
    Color pixelColor;

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmapImage.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmapImage.Width; x++)
        {
            pixelColor = bitmapImage.GetPixel(x, y);
            A = pixelColor.A;
            R = (byte)(255 - pixelColor.R);
            G = (byte)(255 - pixelColor.G);
            B = (byte)(255 - pixelColor.B);
            bitmapImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb((int)A, (int)R, (int)G, (int)B));
        }
    }

}
```

from: http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/image-processing-in-c-sharp-inverting-an-image/

If you want read more about your problem and color matrix, please proceed with the following link: https://web.archive.org/web/20141230042200/http://bobpowell.net/negativeimage.aspx

Comment: -1 for suggesting the super slow iteration through each pixel; +1 for link to Bob Powell.

Comment: As said before this is SUPER SLOW! Thanks anyways

Comment: This is terribly slow. Details: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406045/Why-Use-of-GetPixel-and-SetPixel-is-So-Inefficient

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting `Matrix33` or `Matrix44`.  My understanding is that `Matrix33` would be the alpha component, so I suspect you're making your entire image transparent.

Try setting `Matrix33 = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I used "SIMD Supported Vectors" to make a code faster then pointers.Its under System.Numerics namespace.But before using these classes you need to get the update for System.Numerics from NuGet.Just search for System.Numerics.Anyways thats my class to invert the image

```
public class VBitmap : IDisposable
{        

    public short Width { get; private set; }
    public short Height { get; private set; }
    public int Stride { get; private set; }
    public int PixelLenght { get; private set; }
    public byte BytesperPixel { get; private set; }
    public PixelFormat PixelFormat { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Pixels { get; private set; }

    public VBitmap(string path)
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(path))
        {
            BitmapData bmpdata = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
            Width = checked((short)bmp.Width);
            Height = checked((short)bmp.Height);
            Stride = bmpdata.Stride;
            PixelLenght = Stride * Height;
            BytesperPixel = checked((byte)(Stride / Width));
            PixelLenght = (PixelLenght % 16) != 0 ? PixelLenght + (PixelLenght % 16) : PixelLenght;
            PixelFormat = bmp.PixelFormat;
            Pixels = new byte[PixelLenght];

            Marshal.Copy(bmpdata.Scan0, Pixels, 0, PixelLenght);
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpdata);
        }
    }
    ~VBitmap()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void InvertPixels()
    {
        byte[] resultarray = Pixels;
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* result_ptr = resultarray)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < PixelLenght; i += 16)
                    (~new Vector<byte>(Pixels, i)).CopyTo(resultarray, i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void InvertPixels(string name)
    {
        byte[] resultarray = Pixels;
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* result_ptr = resultarray)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < PixelLenght; i += 16)
                    (~new Vector<byte>(Pixels, i)).CopyTo(resultarray, i);
                SaveImage(name);
            }
        }
    }

    public unsafe void SaveImage(string name)
    {
        fixed (byte* p_ptr = Pixels)
        {
            using (Bitmap resultbmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height, Stride, PixelFormat, (IntPtr)p_ptr))
            {
                resultbmp.Save(name, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Width = 0;
        Height = 0;
        Stride = 0;
        PixelLenght = 0;
        BytesperPixel = 0;
        Pixels = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Usage.Note:To get best performance from vectors you need to run your code on Release Mode:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new VBitmap("testp.png").InvertPixels("qq.jpg");//Inverts the given bitmap and saves it.   
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var gfxPicture = Graphics.FromImage(img);
```

==>

```
var gfxPicture = Graphics.FromImage(bmpPicture);
```

DrawImage could distort image, GetPixel is slow, Try WPF imaging API

Comment: I changed it but it didn't help. Could you post a WPF code snippet? Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, I'm trying to create an inverted screenshot of an application.