# Color invert performance boost for Tiff images - C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, colors

I'm using Winforms. In my form I have a picturebox where I load tiff documents. I use the code below to invert the colors back and forth in the document on button click. The problem with my code is, it is very slow. How do I convert the colors of the images faster?

Image info:

- Image Size: 8.5 x 11 inch
- Pixel Density: 300 x 300 pixel/inch
- Pixel Dimensions - 2550 x 3300 pixels (usually because I open different documents to view)

  ```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
      for (int y = 0; (y <= (pic.Height - 1)); y++)
      {
          for (int x = 0; (x <= (pic.Width - 1)); x++)
          {
              Color inv = pic.GetPixel(x, y);
              inv = Color.FromArgb(255, (255 - inv.R), (255 - inv.G), (255 - inv.B));
              pic.SetPixel(x, y, inv);
          }
      }
      pictureBox1.Image = pic;

  }
  ```

Comment: Have you try to search for something like *"invert color fast c#"*? [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376187/1997232).

Comment: How much time is it taking? On average what is the Height and Width of the image?

Comment: Well your code iterates over each pixel to invert again after a button click. Have you though of storing (in memory) both versions of the same image (normal and inverted) and switch those with the button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetPixel and SetPixel are really slow due too many reasons. Also it is often a bad idea to nest loops. Take a look at the following link for some faster implementation (not optimal but closer)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1989/Image-Processing-for-Dummies-with-C-and-GDI-Part

It involves using unsafe code and the LockPixel method of Images.

Code from the link (You need to allow unsafe code in the project settings)

```
public static bool Invert(Bitmap b)
{
    // GDI+ still lies to us - the return format is BGR, NOT RGB. 
    BitmapData bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), 
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb); 
    int stride = bmData.Stride; 
    System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0; 
    unsafe 
    { 
        byte * p = (byte *)(void *)Scan0;
        int nOffset = stride - b.Width*3; 
        int nWidth = b.Width * 3;
        for(int y=0;y < b.Height;++y)
        {
            for(int x=0; x < nWidth; ++x )
            {
                p[0] = (byte)(255-p[0]);
                ++p;
            }
            p += nOffset;
        }
    }

    b.UnlockBits(bmData);

    return true;
}
```

If this code is not working since you have different image formats  then you need to modify some parts, in terms of the size of a pixel. (its constant 3 in the example)
You can get this by calculation it the following way:

```
int pixelSize = imageData.Stride/image.Width;
```

and replace

```
PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
```

with

```
b.PixelFormat
```

Comment: How would i use the code with the button click event? @CSharpie

Comment: Jus call Invert((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image); and if that doesnt update 
pictureBox1.Refresh();

Comment: I had to add the little Refresh(); after Invert((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image); Thanks for you help. The code preforms very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question:

[Inverting image returns a black image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11779809/153923)

Dan uses a color matrix with image attributes in [his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11781561/153923).

Here is how you would use it (untested):

Declare your Color Matrix so you don't have to keep redefining it every time:

```
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix m_colorMatrix;

    private void Init()
    {
        // create the negative color matrix
        m_colorMatrix = new System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix(new float[][] {
            new float[] {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, -1, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            new float[] {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
        });
    }
```

Now, in your button Click event, supply your Picture Box control:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var source = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        //create a blank bitmap the same size as original
        var bmpInvert = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);

        //get a graphics object from the new image
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpInvert))
        {

            // create some image attributes
            var attributes = new System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes();

            attributes.SetColorMatrix(m_colorMatrix);

            g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
                        0, 0, source.Width, source.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

            pictureBox1.Image = bmpInvert;
        }
    }
```

Since I have included the Graphics object is in a **using** block, you should not call the `Dispose` method like he does.

That may get you what you need, but I don't have anything to test it with.

Comment: Dans code seems to look good, but i dont know how i could call his code with button click.

Comment: @taji01 , take a look at the edited version, with code. +1 if it helps; mark as answer later if it solves your issue.

Comment: When i run the code and click on the button. An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Comment: What line does the exception come on? What is the text of the message? It could be a simple fix.